# Explicit computation of the diameter of a point in the algebraic closure

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions, local-field

Let $(k,\operatorname{ord})$ be a valued local (or even just henselian field), $\tilde{k}$ its algebraic closure. Let $\alpha\in \tilde{k}$. Define the diameter of $\alpha$ as

$$\Delta_k(\alpha) = \Delta(\alpha) = \min \{\operatorname{ord}(\alpha'-\alpha)\mid \alpha'\in \tilde{k}, k\text{-conjugate to } \alpha\}.$$

To gain a better understanding, I would like to explicitly compute $\Delta(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ (perhaps $3+i2\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_3$). How would I do this?

Comment: What are the conjugates of $\alpha=3+2i$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't know. I assume $3-2i$ is one, but there surely must be more.

Comment: Correct, that is one. What is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$?

Comment: $X^2 - 6X +13$?

Comment: Correct. Its coefficients are in $\Bbb{Q}_p$, implying that its zeros are ALL the conjugates.